# No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory while accessing the axis webservice

Tags: java, apache, jar, apache-axis, webservices-client

Getting the below error while accessing the webservice..Tried applying the common-logging.jar but issue din resolved.

org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory while accessing the axis webservice

able to access the same service with main method from a test project which includes jaxrpc,mail.jar,wsdl4.jar,commons-discovery-0.2.jar,commons-logging-api-...as shown below
1[image: Jar list for test project]

but the same service is giving the issue  which contains the below jar list..have added commons-discovery-0.4 as well in addition to 0.2

[image]

Comment: tryied adding commons-logging to buildpath but dint worked

Comment: Remove duplicate entries of jar files commons-httpclient & commons-discovery and others if you have.

Comment: are you using maven for dependency management?

Comment: have tried with removing the duplicates..no luck...thanks for responding..Yes Sachin we are using maven

Comment: This error is coming because axis also has its commons-logging dependency, which you can remove by maven dependency management.

Comment: axis2-kernel depend on commons-logging remove it using exclude tag in pom.xml

Comment: should I exclude axis2-kernel ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130185/discussion-between-sachinsarawgi-and-javalearner).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have dependency-hierarchy tab in your IDE. So for checking the dependency tree Install maven as mentioned below:

> Download maven bin zipped file
>
> Unzip and paste in Program Files folder
>
> Edit Path Environment Variable (add maven bin folder location in the path)
>
> Go to project home directory
>
> Run following command: `mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=output.txt`

This will generate maven dependency tree.

Now check which all dependency in your pom.xml is showing multiple times (use Ctrl + F) feature or do it manually. Now remove the dependency which is showing more them two times using `<exclusions>` tag (already explained you for axis2-kernel, same like that).

Now add separately commons-loging maven dependency:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

This process will remove duplicate dependency and remove your commons-logging framework problem.

If face issue just comment.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is resolved by adding the below to commons-logging.properties and added the file to classpath.

org.apache.commons.logging.Log = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl

Answer (score 2):

In case this would help somebody struggling with this exception on a JUnit unit test, the below did not work for me.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", 
"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", 
"org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger");
}
```

what worked was replacing the first statement with the below.

```
System.setProperty(LogFactory.FACTORY_PROPERTY, LogFactory.FACTORY_DEFAULT);
```